# Elixir Plug configure for specific file

Tags: http-headers, elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I have defined a `plug` in my `App.Endpoint` module in the following way:

```
plug(
  Plug.Static,
  at: "/",
  from: :main_web,
  gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images webfonts favicon.ico robots.txt sw.js manifest.json js/app.js),
  headers: %{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"}
)
```

Everything works as expected except that this plug is not applied for `/js/app.js`

I am currently not able to serve just `/js/app.js`, but instead am only able to specify `js` which will serve all the files in the `/js` directory.

How can I specify just this `js/app.js` file and not others?

I have tried

```
only: ~w(... app.js)
only_matching: ~w(... js/app.js)
```

But I always receive 404 for `/js/app.js`

Comment: From the [source](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/10948b83a4441d4ef0f09a7563d307b1d3903080/lib/plug/static.ex) it looks like only the first segment of the URL is checked against the `only` list. You could add a special route for `/js/app.js` and manually serve the JS file using `send_file`.